# Need help to finish a drop down to be active only when clicked. (HTML and CSS)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, onclick

Tried really hard to figure this out. Nothing.

Take a look: http://liveweave.com/VDqJTf

I just need a simple activation on click, so it will work well also on mobile.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a minimal example, where it uses only CSS and HTML.

```css
/* Start Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
/* End Praveen's Reset for Fiddle ;) */

nav ul {display: block;}
nav > ul > li {display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px; position: relative;}
nav ul ul {position: absolute; left: 0; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #999; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: -1px; width: 100px; background-color: #fff; display: none;}
nav ul input {display: none;}
nav ul ul li {display: block;}
nav ul input:checked + ul {display: block;}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>
        Item 1
        <input type="radio" name="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        Item 2
        <input type="radio" name="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        Item 3
        <input type="radio" name="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Would checkbox work on this method as well? (guessing that it would make the dropdown toggle when clicked)

Comment: @KiiroSora09 Checkbox will make all menus to be displayed at all time! `:(` Radio makes sure that only one is displayed at any time!

Comment: You're right, I did not think of that. Though the dropdown will still not hide if no other menu item is clicked.

Comment: @KiiroSora09 There are a lot of possibilities that it iwll hide.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, what possibilities?